# fetch contact from xConnect based on contact facet

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I'm using sitecore 9.1.1

I'm trying to get contact who's first name is "myfirstnametest" but I'm getting count zero in result for contacts even I have record with this contact facet.

```
using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
var results3 = client.Contacts.Where(c => c.GetFacet<PersonalInformation>().FirstName == "myfirstnametest").GetBatchEnumerator();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Raman said, you need to make sure you are index PII information before it can show up.

Also you query should be like this

```
client.Contacts.Where(x => x.Personal().FirstName == "Tommy")
  .WithExpandOptions(new ContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey))
  GetBatchEnumerator();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Experience Profile and List Manager interfaces rely on personal data being available in the xDB index. As the FirstName facet is marked as [PIISensitive], you will not be able to use it by default.

To use contact facets marked [PIISensitive] in the custom predicate, [please enable indexing of PII sensitive data in the xDB index](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/enable-indexing-of-pii-sensitive-data-in-the-xdb-index.html).

I am able to see the segmented list based on FirstName after I enabled the indexing of PII sensitive data in the xDB index.